# Algorithm to find figures using input points

Tags: algorithm, math, graph

I have just discussed with student and he told me him task, and I think it is interesting.
The task.
There are file with points like:

```
Point0: x=1; y=4;
Point1: x=199; y=45;
Point2: x=42; y=333;
Point3: x=444; y=444;
...
PointN: x=nnn; y=mmm;
```

You should find polygons and draw them. Each polygon present as internal
I mean something like this:

```
---------
| -----  |
| |    | |
| |----| | 
|        |
|--------|
```

And question what algorithm can you advice to use in this case?
I understand this is from graph theory , but want opinion of other.
Thanks.

Comment: it's not clear how you are deciding which points belong to which polygon.. could you please explain more?

Comment: Polygon does not cross other polygons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idea: Find the [convex hul](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull)l of all the points. For all the points that do not belong to the hull repeat the algorithm until no points left.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer I have not thought  about this algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably find a distance matrix for all the points and then do iterations like the following:

1. Find the largest distance
2. Draw rectangle for the two points which correspond to the found distance
3. Remove these points from the list
4. Repeat